# Why is constant instance of a value type can NOT change its properties while constant instance of a reference type can?

Tags: swift, reference, constants

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of Property. I saw the statements and code below from "swift programming language 2.1".

```
struct FixedLengthRange {
    var firstvalue: Int
    let length: Int
}

let rangeOfFourItems = FixedLengthRange(firstvalue: 0, length: 4)
rangeOfFourItems.firstvalue = 8 //error: cannot assign to property: rangeOfFourItems is a "let" constant
```

And the book provided the following explanation for the error:

> This behavior is due to structures being value types. When an instance
>   of a value type is marked as a constant, so are all of its properties.
>
> The same is not true for classes, which are reference types. If you
>   assign an instance of a reference type to a constant, you can still
>   change that instance’s variable properties.

Why is constant instance of a value type can NOT change its properties while constant instance of a reference type can? What is the reason behind it? The book did say how but failed to explain why. I think it is good practice to understand the reasons behind how things the way they are. Could someone please kindly explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is constant instance of a value type can NOT change its properties

Because value type is treated as an indivisible unit: it gets copied on assignment, passing it as a parameter behaves like a copy, and so using const-ness locks down the entire `struct`. In a sense, `rangeOfFourItems` variable represents the structure itself, not a pointer or a reference to it.

> while constant instance of a reference type can?

This is not entirely correct to say that declaring a const variable of reference type makes the instance constant as well. Only the reference is constant, not the instance.

If you think about it, that is the only way this could be meaningfully implemented, because multiple variables can reference the same by-reference instance. If one of these variables is constant and the other one is not constant, assigning a non-const reference to a constant variable could not possibly lock down the referenced object, which would lock out the non-const reference as well:

```
var a = ByRefType()
let b = a; // b is a constant reference to the same instance as "a"
a.property = newValue; // Prohibiting this assignment would be inconsistent
```

Of course the constant variable itself (e.g. `b` above) could not be re-assigned, unlike the non-constant variable `a`.

Comment: A constant reference to an instance of a value type means that the the reference itself cannot be changed to point to any other value type instance, it shouldn't affect the value type itself or its properties, if I understand correctly. So why does this make the value type's properties immutable as well? It's not like there can be other references to this particular value type.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!!